# Jump() is called several times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I call the `Jump()` function using `Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")`. But this function is called several times and the character jumps 3 times higher. 
I also used to check is grounded raycast and `OnCollisionEnter2D` but still there was such a problem.

```
void Update()
{
    int yMovement = (int)Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (yMovement == 1)
    {
        Jump();
    }
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(new Vector2(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y - 0.5f), new Vector2(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y - 0.51f), groundLayer);
}
void Jump()
{
    if (!isGrounded)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        print("jump");
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(1, 1);
        r.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, use FixedUpdate, second of all,  "transform.position.y - 0.51f" is the 1 intentional? Finally, can you show how you used OnCollisionEnter2D?

Comment: Call jump: set grounded to false, apply force, (physics hasn't updated yet), immediately set grounded to the return of `Physics2D.OverlapArea` (probably true as physics hasn't updated yet).

Comment: @Draco18s 
Does not work. The fact is that when a character only comes off the ground "isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea (new Vector2 (transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y - 0.5f), new Vector2 (transform.position.x + 0.5 f, transform.position.y - 0.51f), groundLayer);" this line sets the value isGrounded true

Comment: ...that's what I just said. After a jump, it sets that value to true, allowing another jump.

Comment: @Draco18s Oh sorry. Do you happen to know possible solutions to this problem?

Comment: Tomer already gave you a hint with using FixedUpdate, as did I when I said, "physics hasn't run yet."

Comment: @Draco18s This didn’t help. The method is still called several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Overlap Circle Smaller and Adjust the Sequence
1) Check IsGrounded 
2) Then Jump

Instead of Jumping first then Checking IsGrounded.